# MySQL: How To Add IF EXISTS Then UPDATE Else INSERT?

Tags: mysql

I need to add `IF EXISTS Then UPDATE Else INSERT` to the following queries:

```
-- Exist
UPDATE TargetTable
SET ColumnD = '...', ColumnE = '...'
WHERE ...

-- Doesn't Exist
INSERT INTO TargetTable
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, ColumnE, ColumnF, ColumnG
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnB, ColumnC from SourceTable) derived_table
WHERE ColumnB = 'a';
```

**NOTE:** **Both `Source` and `Target` tables have no `PK` due to the nature of data in it.**

EDIT: the "duplicate" question/answer doesn't work for me because my tables has no primary keys.

Comment: The question @Shift'NTab referenced should work as long as you have at least one unique key; but since you have no PK, I doubt you'd have a unique one. In that case, you'll need procedural code; you can either do that in your client language or a stored procedure; MySQL does not support it's procedural elements in normal queries.

Comment: Make sense. I have already tried the suggested solution but, like you said, doesn't work in my case since there is no PK

Comment: Care to explain why there is no pk or combination of unique columns?

Comment: because an item "Box" can be move in and out of a room multiple times per day. The table records the box's in-out times along with many other objects.

Comment: Sidenote: Your insert...select makes no sense unless `Column[A|D|E|F|G]` are local variables whose declarations have been omitted.